# upgrading from magento2.2.5 to 2.3.5 I'm facing this issue

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.2.5, magento2.3.5-p1

I'm upgrading from **magento2.2.5** to **2.3.5** I'm facing this issue

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar' not found in app/code/<Vendor>/<ModuleName>/registration.php file


<?php
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
     'Vendor_Module',
     __DIR__
 );
```

can anyone please help me.

Comment: Share the code of this file : app/code/<Vendor>/<ModuleName>/registration.php

Comment: updated the code in the ticket

Comment: Have you check by disabling/Remove this extension? if you disable does above error gone?

Comment: I'm having this issue. What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue with one of your module that does not have proper code in `registration.php` file and it does not have this class `Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar` either delete the module or update the code of of your `registration.php` file in your module

Comment: i think you need to upgrade their composer.json file one simple way is to take complete backup of you app/code folder and remove mdules then upgrade and put back those modules

Comment: remove generated

Comment: yes removed the generated, pub and var data

Comment: still you are getting error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111487/discussion-between-venkata-prasad-and-chikku).

Comment: yes still same issue

Comment: @Pramod Please let me know the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the composer version-related issue

Try after update composer version

`composer self-update --2`